# How to fix "syntax error: unexpected shim, expecting comma or )" in chaincode?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I have the chaincode, which should encrypt data and put to ledger and do query.

I have updated fabric binaries, but in other fabric samples chaincodes this line is the same and do not have any errors.

```golang
func (s *SmartContract) queryPatient(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response { 
     if len(args) != 1 {
         return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 1")
     }

    patientAsBytes, err := fc.Decrypter(APIstub, args[0])
    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error(err.Error())
    }

     return shim.Success(patientAsBytes)
 }
```

Error is directing to the 
`queryPatient(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response { .`

Comment: Nothing wrong with the syntax in this code, so it cannot generate that error. Either the error is coming from somewhere else or the actual code is different.

Answer (score 0):

Don`t know whats in sc.Response but in all the cases you were returning shim.Error() type. As per terminology stub i think you were using gRPC, it should return response and an error.